# Scaling the MAE by the mean of non zero points for intermittent data

Tags: forecasting, error, mae

I am currently trying to find a way of scaling the MAE for my intermittent data.

The data is always greater than 0 and is intermittent, with long periods of zeros.

I have read a few papers that suggest scaling the MAE by the MEAN of the test data ([Measuring forecast accuracy by Hoover](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/5055533_Measuring_Forecast_Accuracy_Omissions_in_Today's_Forecasting_Engines_and_Demand-Planning_Software) or [Advantages of the MAD/Mean Ratio over the MAPE by  Kolassa & Schütz](https://ideas.repec.org/a/for/ijafaa/y2007i6p40-43.html)).

Though this solves the issue of scaling the MAE I cannot understand why for Intermittent data one wouldn't scale by the MEAN of non-zero data.

I have already looked at metrics such as MAPE, sMAPE, MASE and a few others but they often have some issue with intermittent data (the exception being MASE though harder to interpret)

To me this would have the benefit of brining all data points to either center around 1 or remain 0. If one divides by the MEAN of all points this could result in time series being centered much close to 0.

I can find no papers on this so I'm assuming I'm missing something seriously obvious.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see no issue with scaling the MAE by the mean of non-zeros.

It amounts to expressing the MAE as a percentage of the mean of non-zero demands (or whatever you are measuring), whereas dividing the MAE by the overall mean expresses it as a percentage of that. It's just a question of interpretation, and of making errors for different series comparable, and of what interpretation you are most comfortable with.

I hope you are aware that the MAE (or *any* scaled multiple of the MAE, whether scaled by the overall mean or by the mean of non-zeros, or by the in-sample random walk MAE as for the MASE) can be *heavily* misleading as a forecast accuracy measure for intermittent time series. Specifically, the smallest MAE (or multiple thereof) will probably be achieved by a flat zero forecast, which is usually not very useful. See Kolassa ([2016](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2015.12.004) and [2020](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ijforecast.2019.02.017), both in the *International Journal of Forecasting*).